# Pig Queries stuck on 0% Mapreduce Launcher when dumping file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm having some difficulties with Pig. I'm running Hortonworks 2.4 with hadoop and pig installed. I'm trying to run some queries and after having everything run successfully, I've found that I'm starting to get issues with dumping anything.

Anytime I dump my mapreduce job stalls at 0%. I'm more than likely assuming this is tied to a lack of resources but am unsure how to things up. I've even allocated another 8GB of memory for my virtual machine in the settings.

Here what I have done,

```
a  = load '/user/assignment2/routes.dat' using PigStorage(',') AS (airline:chararray, airline_id:chararray, start_airport:chararray, start_id:chararray, end_airport:chararray, end_id:chararray, codeshare:chararray, stops:chararray, equipment:chararray);
b = foreach a generate start_airport, end_airport;
c = distinct b;
d = limit c 5;
```

Comment: Just because the VM has 8gb doesn't mean that yarn can access it all by default or that yarn is even running. By the way, Pig runs fine without Hadoop in local mode and HDP is end of life

Comment: Any ideas around potential solutions? Is there a way to change yarns access to resources?

Comment: Yes. Ambari can be logged into to see what resources YARN is configured with.. You also need to open the ResourceManager UI to see why jobs are stuck